# Find specific part of string based on condition

Tags: c#, string

I have below comma separated string. This string contains relation which is needed in the application for processing.

```
string userInputColRela = "input1:Student_Name, input2:Student_Age";
```

Now, i need to extract `Student_Name` if i provide input as `input1` and `Student_Age` if the input provided is `input2`.

How can i achieve this? I know i can go with looping but that will be a little lengthy solution, what is other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the input string by splitting firstly on the comma, then again on the semi-colon to get the key-value pairs contained in it in dictionary form. For example:

```
string userInputColRela = "input1: Student_Name, input2: Student_Age";

var inputLookup = userInputColRela
    .Split(',')
    .Select(a => a.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(a => a[0].Trim(), a => a[1].Trim());

var studentName = inputLookup["input1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your strings are always in the format `input1:Student_Name, input2:Student_Age` then probably you can use a `Dictionary<k,v>` and `Split()` function like

```
        string userInputColRela = "input1:Student_Name, input2:Student_Age";
        string input = "input1";
        var args = userInputColRela.Split(',');
        Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in args)
        {
            var data = item.Split(':');
            inputs.Add(data[0], data[1]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(inputs[input]);
```